# Caption positioning with float package

Tags: floats

I'm using the `float` package and I defined a new float environment. I noticed that when there's a figure inside float with `width=\textwidth` the space between the figure and the caption is doubled. However, when it's something like `width=0.9\textwidth` or other number, the space is the standard for a float environment.

I simply use `\vspace{-\abovecaptionskip}` when the figure has the width of the text, but I don't know why this happens and if there is some explanation.

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\usepackage{float}
\newfloat{scheme}{htbp}{schemes}

\begin{document}

    \begin{scheme}[h]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{}
        \caption{Lorem ipsum}
    \end{scheme}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Missing % after `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{}`; this creates a space which starts a new line:

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\usepackage{float}
\newfloat{scheme}{htbp}{schemes}

\begin{document}

    \begin{scheme}[h]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{}%
        \caption{Lorem ipsum}
    \end{scheme}

        \begin{scheme}[h]
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]{}%
            \caption{Lorem ipsum}
        \end{scheme}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I see, but it is strange that this space won't appear in a float like `figure` neither when the width is different from `\textwidth`.

Comment: Sometimes spaces are ignored.  Usually this involves \par or \ignorespaces.